# What tricks or techniques were used to speed up AmigaOS boot

Tags: amiga, operating-system, amiga-workbench-3.1, amiga-workbench-1.3

I did an installation of Workbench 3.1 grounds up. The system takes a moment to boot, well over a minute. I've watched a YouTube video where the system booted in seconds. I have another image of Workbench1.3 on different SD card, it boots in seconds as well. Is it done using software, patches or skilled manipulation of files like boot-sequence, startup-sequence?

My setup:

CDTV KS 3.1, 030 MMU 64MB Fast RAM (TF536), 2GB system partition only (sd2ide), disabled extended rom.

Comment: Few questions: "grounds up" means no extra cruft? Roughly what's your hardware? (CPU+Disk) Did you test the 1.3 system on the same hardware? No workbench should take over a minute even booting from a floppy...

Comment: can you post your startup sequence?

Comment: are you are using the CDTV specific Kickstart ROM on a system that isn't a CDTV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, booting an Amiga from an HDD is quite fast, and can certainly be far less than 30 seconds even when a significant number of drivers and small applications are loaded via commands in `S:Startup-Sequence`.

It should normally take only ~5 seconds to initialize the hardware and see the display of the CLI window (see below about cold vs. warm boot times). From there, the delay in reaching the Workbench screen is determined mainly by the commands you spawn via your `Startup-Sequence`, with the only *essential* commands being `SetPatch` and `BindDrivers`.

It should be noted that a cold boot will be longer than a warm boot simply because any HD boot ought to be running `SetPatch`. The inclusion of `SetPatch` thus adds an extra system initialization sequence lasting ~5 seconds for cold boot only.

`BindDrivers` is necessary to load Disk-based device drivers if you are using any. This is normally a quick process, unless the device driver has a long initialization process for whatever hardware it is controlling.

If you want to keep things to a minimum, you can follow these two commands with a simple `LoadWB` and `EndCLI`. This will completely initialize the system ready for use and the only delay is going to be loading whatever icons from the disk that you use to populate the Workbench desktop. The minimum would be a simple `.info` file for your HDD.

Of course, you can include as many commands (and sub-scripts!) in your `Startup-Sequence` as desired. Each one of these will add some delay, even if only simple DOS commands setting up your environment. You can speed up the repeated use of common DOS commands by using the `Resident` command to keep them in RAM.

Comment: Hm, IIRC one main addition to 3.1 vs 3.0 was the introduction of CD-ROM features. Since OP runs on a CDTV, maybe that's the culprit.

Comment: what also helps is to call commands using full path, ex: `c:assign` instead of `assign` to avoid path lookup

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre or keep them in memory using `resident` before executing them a bunch of times

Comment: true, although not all commands can be made resident IIRC

Answer (score 2):

With a spare megabyte of RAM you could also install Workbench or equivalent in a resident bootable RAM disk ("RAD:"), so you could boot from RAM with no moving parts.

Of course that will only work for a warm boot/warm start, not the first "cold" boot.

Some details here: https://www.amigareport.com/ar139/p1-6.html

Answer (score 1):

Another factor is the SCSI ID; make sure your HDD is set to 0, and set a lower number than std. in HDToolBox for max. ID, as low as possible, and save the new info to your drive.
That way, the SCSI adapter will stop searching for drives as soon as it can, speeding things up a bit.